# Can an SKFieldNode be used to also alter the zRotation of a particle?

Tags: sprite-kit, skemitternode, skfieldnode

I'm trying to make an SKFieldNode attract water particles toward the node when using an SKEmitterNode as the particle system. When moving toward the SKFieldNode's location using a field like the radialGravityField, **I want the particles to also rotate to face the field node**.

The SKFieldNode documentation doesn't appear to have any reference to altering zRotation of particles so I presume this is not possible. Any thoughts here?

How else could I achieve this affect? Do I need to create my own particle system to achieve this? How much slower than SKEmitterNode will that be?

Answer (score 0):

SKEmitterNode does not have a physics property. Potentially having thousands of particles in view with physics in play would bog down the hardware.

If you are looking to add physics to a particle effect you will have to create your own custom class for that. As for the speed question, that will all depend on how many particles, their properties and the physics involved. You are gonna have to trial and error this.